# How to show json data in viewpage

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

I am trying to write a simple andriod app
A function has been implemented:
The json data that reads the web api is displayed in the textview and works fine.
When I want to display it in the viewpage, the layout is loaded correctly, but the class that reads json data is not loaded.

This code is for viewpage

```
    public class dboElc_5min extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ViewPager pager = null;
        private MyPagerAdapter adapter = null;
        private View[] views = new View[2];
        private int[] viewId = {R.layout.activity_dbo_elc_5min_1, R.layout.activity_dbo_elc_5min_2};

        private List<View> viewList = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbo_elc_5min);

            initViews();

            adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(viewList);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        private void initViews() {
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.id_viewpager);

            viewList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < viewId.length; i++) {
                views[i] = View.inflate(this, viewId[i], null);
                viewList.add(views[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is one of page

```
    public class dboElc_5min_1 extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
        SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
        TextView mTextViewResult;
        RequestQueue mQueue;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbo_elc_5min_1);
            mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            jsonParse();
            mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
        }
        public void jsonParse()
        {
            String url ="http://***/test/api/ELC_5min";
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray array= response.getJSONArray("Elc_5min");
                                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String XElc_A_Vrs = object.getString("XElc_A_Vrs");
                                    String XElc_A_Vst = object.getString("XElc_A_Vst");
                                    String XElc_A_Vtr = object.getString("XElc_A_Vtr");
                                    String XElc_A_Ir = object.getString("XElc_A_Ir");
                                    String XElc_A_Is = object.getString("XElc_A_Is");
                                    String XElc_A_It = object.getString("XElc_A_It");
                                    String Elc_A_KWH = object.getString("Elc_A_KWH");

                                    mTextViewResult.setText("        "+"RS : "+XElc_A_Vrs+"V"+"\n"+
                                            "    "+"ST : "+XElc_A_Vst+"V"+"\n"+
                                            "    "+"TR : "+XElc_A_Vtr+"V"+"\n\n\n"+
                                            "             "+"R : " +XElc_A_Ir+"A"+"\n"+
                                            "    "+"S : " +XElc_A_Is+"A"+"\n"+
                                            "    "+"T : " +XElc_A_It+"A"+"\n"+
                                            "   "      +Elc_A_KWH+"KWH"+"\n");
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            mQueue.add(request);
        }
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            jsonParse();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
```

This is my PageAdapter

```
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        private List<View> viewList ;

        public MyPagerAdapter(List<View> viewList) {
            this.viewList = viewList;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            container.addView(viewList.get(position));
            return viewList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView(viewList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return viewList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }
```

As a result of the implementation, only the layout is captured, and my json data cannot be displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you post the error log? @Jyun Kai